# How do I find the instance to which a method belongs?

Tags: javascript

// minified base class code (if the uncompressed code is needed, I'll post it)
    function Class(){}Class.prototype.construct=function(){};Class.extend=function(c){var a=function(){arguments[0]!==Class&&this.construct.apply(this,arguments)},d=new this(Class),f=this.prototype;for(var e in c){var b=c[e];if(b instanceof Function)b.$=f;d[e]=b}a.prototype=d;a.extend=this.extend;return a};

```
// custom event class
var Event = Class.extend({
    handlers: [],
    // stores the event handler
    subscribe: function(handler, thisObj) {
        this.handlers.push([handler, thisObj]);
    },
    // calls the event handlers
    fire: function() {
        for(i in this.handlers) {
            var handler = this.handlers[i];
            handler[0].apply(handler[1]);
        }
    }
});
var Class2 = Class.extend({
    myEvent: new Event(), // the event
    test: function() { // fires the event
        this.myEvent.fire(this);
    }
});
var Class3 = Class.extend({
    construct: function(model) {
        this.name = "abc";
        model.myEvent.subscribe(this.handler, this); // subscribe to the event
    },
    handler: function() {
        alert(this.name); // alerts 'abc'
    }
});
var instance1 = new Class2();
var instance2 = new Class3(instance1);
instance1.test();
```

The only way to make the event handler code to work with the good 'this' is by adding a new argument ('thisObj') to the 'subscribe' method? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour you're getting is due to the fact that when you pass a "method" to a function, the receiving function has no idea it's a method. It's just a block of javascript that needs to get executed.

Prototype gets around this issue with the `bind` method

- http://api.prototypejs.org/language/function/prototype/bind/

You can get similar behaviour (I didn't look at the implementation details of bind) by using a closure.

```
var Class3 = Class.extend({
    construct: function(model) {
        this.name = "abc";
        //model.myEvent.subscribe(this.handler, this); // subscribe to the event
        var self = this;
        model.myEvent.subscribe(function() {self.handler()});
    },
    handler: function() {
        alert(this.name); // alerts 'abc'
    }
});
```

Or apply some similar functionality to the subscribe method of your custom event class.

**EDITED** To reflect CMS's observations. Thanks!

Comment: When I run this code in Firefox I get: self.handler is not a function.. I will read more about these closures.. and look at the Prototype implementation of bind.. jQuery also has $.proxy which I think does the same thing, but I am working on a little project which should be independent of any JavaScript library. Anyway.. thanks!

Comment: An anonymous function that is executed immediately, will always have the `this` value pointing to the global object, i.e. `(function () { return this === window; })(); // true`, you don't need that function, you only need to assign the `var self = this;` in the enclosing function (construct) and use a simple anonymous function (like the one you return) to execute `self.handler();`.

Comment: I didn't know the first part about the anonymous function having `this` refer to the global object. That's good to know. Thanks!